# PS4 wont beep twice and wont display

Tags: ps4, ps-remote-play

I was watching you tube and uploading a game when suddenly my PS4 switched off. When I switch it on, it doesn't pick up on HDMI and it switches back off after 30 seconds or so. When I try to do the safe mode reset "Pressing the power button until second beep" it doesn't beep twice.

I press the power button and hold for more than 10 seconds and I still don't get the second beep or get to the safe reset screen. What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

With the console switched off, press and hold the power button for as long as it takes to hear the two beeps. The console may switch on with a single beep, switch off again, and then start with two beeps.

[According to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDfG7x2LkkQ), the beeps will be around 5 seconds apart.